# What would be an effective way to create an interactive (and accessible) two-dimensional diagram for the web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, diagram

Consider the diagram below, which illustrates some concepts and the relationship between them (the diagram attempts to show that the concepts of seriousness and playfulness are not opposed, but stand in a more complicated relationship):

[image: Diagram of relationships between concepts of play/dullness and seriousness/emptiness]

I would like to be able to use this in a web page, in an interactive form, such that if the user hovers over/touches:

- *play*, then the top half of the diagram, and the horizontal axis, light up
- *seriousness*, then the left side and the vertical axis, light up

and so on. And if the user hovers over/touches:

- *foolish*, then that whole quadrant, and the parts of the two axes associated with it, light up

and so on. I hope that makes sense.

## HTML/CSS

I can't think of a way that I could start doing this with HTML/CSS, because here we have a two-dimensional logical relationship between, whereas everything in HTML/CSS is based on the idea of a hierarchical tree. And I don't see a way to represent these relationships in a hierarchical tree.

(I also don't see a way to make it usefully accessible either.)

Might be there some way to achieve this that?

## `canvas` and JavaScript

Alternatively, I think this is the kind of thing that can be done very well, visually, using JS to draw on a `canvas`. But then it's really only a visual representation, not a semantic one. And I think providing an accessible option would just be providing a description.

(Also I am not quite sure where to begin with JS, but that's a different problem.)

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Html css and js can do that well. Create your html elements, keep them referenced in js and write the relationship logic with js.

Comment: For something like this I would create an interactive SVG.

Comment: What do you want ‘light up’ to look like? Is it just a background color changing or the text as well or …

Comment: What did you use to make that image?, if it was a vector based editor, it will likely have SVG export feature.  If so that's a great starting point, making it interactive is then pretty easy.

Comment: @AHaworth "Lighting up" would really mean that the rest of the thing would be dimmed. But I guess it could also e.g. make text stronger.

Comment: You mention accessible in your title, what sort of accessibility would you envisage? Obviously if it's just a visual change on hover then that won't be sensed by a screen reader user.

Answer (score 1):

As mostly suggested in comments:

- Make an svg
- Add ids to the elements you're interacting with

  - the text boxes
  - the quadrants
  - the axes
- Add css rules for the hover styles
- Add mouseover and mouseout events in js.

The axes are not included and leftover for you to figure out.

```js
    const ids = ['alive', 'foolish', 'dry', 'dead', 'seriousness', 'emptiness', 'play', 'dullness', 'q-11', 'q-12', 'q-21', 'q-22'];
    const elements = [];
    ids.forEach(id => {
        elements[id] = document.getElementById(id);
    })
    elements['alive'].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        elements['q-11'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['alive'].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        elements['q-11'].classList.remove('active');
    });
    elements['foolish'].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        elements['q-12'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['foolish'].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        elements['q-12'].classList.remove('active');
    });
    elements['dry'].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        elements['q-21'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['dry'].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        elements['q-21'].classList.remove('active');
    });
    elements['dead'].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        elements['q-22'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['dead'].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        elements['q-22'].classList.remove('active');
    });
    elements['seriousness'].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        elements['q-11'].classList.add('active');
        elements['q-21'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['seriousness'].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        elements['q-11'].classList.remove('active');
        elements['q-21'].classList.remove('active');
    });
        elements['play'].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        elements['q-11'].classList.add('active');
        elements['q-12'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['play'].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        elements['q-11'].classList.remove('active');
        elements['q-12'].classList.remove('active');
    });
        elements['emptiness'].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        elements['q-12'].classList.add('active');
        elements['q-22'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['emptiness'].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        elements['q-12'].classList.remove('active');
        elements['q-22'].classList.remove('active');
    });
        elements['dullness'].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        elements['q-21'].classList.add('active');
        elements['q-22'].classList.add('active');
    });
    elements['dullness'].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        elements['q-21'].classList.remove('active');
        elements['q-22'].classList.remove('active');
    });
```

```css
    .active {
        fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
        transition: fill 0.5s;
    }

    #alive, #foolish, #dry, #dead, #seriousness, #emptiness, #play, #dullness {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<svg width="132.42525mm" height="65.621933mm" viewBox="0 0 132.42525 65.621933" version="1.1" id="svg5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs id="defs2">
        <rect x="53.557415" y="178.16037" width="249.75241" height="61.754974" id="rect1131"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="78.696609" width="221.33418" height="83.068642" id="rect1075"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="78.696609" width="221.33418" height="83.068642" id="rect1075-6"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="78.696609" width="221.33418" height="83.068642" id="rect1075-60"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="78.696609" width="221.33418" height="83.068642" id="rect1075-4"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="178.16037" width="249.75241" height="61.754974" id="rect1131-5"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="178.16037" width="249.75241" height="61.754974" id="rect1131-9"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="178.16037" width="249.75241" height="61.754974" id="rect1131-5-5"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="178.16037" width="249.75241" height="61.754974" id="rect1131-9-7"/>
        <rect x="53.557415" y="178.16037" width="249.75241" height="61.754974" id="rect1131-5-5-8"/>
    </defs>
    <rect style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" id="q-12" width="66.080322" height="32.678673" x="66.212616" y="0.13229194"/>
    <rect style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" id="q-11" width="66.080322" height="32.678673" x="0.13229166" y="0.13229282"/>
    <rect style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" id="q-21" width="66.080322" height="32.678673" x="0.13229269" y="32.810966"/>
    <rect style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" id="q-22" width="66.080322" height="32.678673" x="66.212616" y="32.810966"/>
    <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-14.038108,-14.327298)">
        <rect style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" id="rect791" width="132.16066" height="65.357353" x="14.1704" y="14.45959"/>
        <a id="alive">
            <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,7.5189877,-2.0243427)" id="text1073" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:32px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1075);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="107.89184" id="tspan4739">Alive</tspan></text>
        </a>
        <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,7.5189877,43.097908)" id="dry" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:32px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1075-6);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="107.89184" id="tspan4741">Dry</tspan></text>
        <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,104.18857,43.374894)" id="dead" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:32px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1075-60);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="107.89184" id="tspan4743">Dead</tspan></text>
        <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,96.730627,-1.6925483)" id="foolish" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:32px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1075-4);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="107.89184" id="tspan4745">Foolish</tspan></text>
        <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,2.4550755,-3.6437849)" id="seriousness" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:24px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1131);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="200.05608" id="tspan4747">Seriousness</tspan></text>
        <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,97.549133,-3.48161)" id="emptiness" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:24px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1131-5);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="200.05608" id="tspan4749">Emptiness</tspan></text>
        <g id="g1473" transform="rotate(90,75.716553,125.29723)"/>
        <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0,0.26458333,-0.26458333,0,130.72605,2.0423203)" id="play" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:18.6667px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1131-9-7);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="195.19035" id="tspan4751">Play</tspan></text>
        <text xml:space="preserve" transform="matrix(0,0.26458333,-0.26458333,0,129.86958,42.90673)" id="dullness" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:18.6667px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1131-5-5-8);display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1"><tspan x="53.556641" y="195.19035" id="tspan4753">Dullness</tspan></text>
        <path style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 14.170401,47.138264 h 2.494323" id="path1100"/>
        <path style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.330634;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 80.252291,56.428263 80.459783,27.324879 Z" id="path1112"/>
        <path style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" d="M 80.461353,15.711137 V 14.445869 Z" id="path1114"/>
    </g>
    <path style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 42.190027,32.943257 24.022586,-0.132291 v 0 z" id="path1102"/>
    <path style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 66.212613,32.810966 30.808033,-0.132289 v 0 z" id="path1104"/>
    <path style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 132.29294,32.810966 h -1.39989 z" id="path1106"/>
    <path style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.265;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 66.214187,64.675868 -0.0016,0.813616 z" id="path1278"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing. I have it running in https://jsfiddle.net already and I think I will be able to work out the additional steps. I appreciate all that effort to do this.

Comment: This looks interesting, but are there accessibility issues?